# Is there any response.status code list for Ext.Ajax.request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, extjs, extjs3

For Ext.form.BasicForm.submit(), the failure case can be handled by

```
failure: function(form, action) {
    switch (action.failureType) {
        case Ext.form.Action.CLIENT_INVALID:
            Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Form fields may not be submitted with invalid values');
            break;
        case Ext.form.Action.CONNECT_FAILURE:
            Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Ajax communication failed');
            break;
        case Ext.form.Action.SERVER_INVALID:
           Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', action.result.msg);
   }
}
```

How about Ext.Ajax.request? Which failure cases would probably induced?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The status is the http status. `200, 401, 404, 500` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my experience, the failure handling for `Ext.form.BasicForm.submit()` and `Ext.Ajax.request()` slightly different in the parameters.

For `Ext.Ajax.request()` failure handling usually i am using following method:

```
        failure:function(response, opts){
            Ext.Msg.show({
                title:'Error code: '+response.status,
                msg:'Server error: '+response.statusText,
                buttons:Ext.Msg.OK,
                icon:Ext.Msg.ERROR
            });
        }
```

Based on above code, first parameter is the one who has important information about errors. Two important properties of `response` is `response.status` and `response.statusText` that you can use for error handling like `switch` statement.

`response.status` will contain status code of HTTP error like 200, 300, 400, 404, 500 etc.

For more detail about what `response` properties has, you can show them by `console.log(response)`.